# Convert an array to a string

Tags: php, arrays, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert PHP array string into an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684553/convert-php-array-string-into-an-array)

Which function can be used to convert an array into a string, maintaining your ability to return the string into an array?

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/684553/convert-php-array-string-into-an-array

Comment: How can "convert **array** to **string**" question be a duplicate (exact, sic!) of "convert **string** to **array**" question? That are **two exactly opposite** operations!

Answer (score 7):

The [`serialize` function](http://docs.php.net/serialize) turns any value into a string.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) function to convert an array into a string:

```
$array = implode(" ", $string); //space as glue
```

If you want to convert it back to an array you can use the explode function:

```
$string = explode(" ", $array); //space as delimiter
```

Comment: And if $array[2] == "Some value"?

Comment: I don't know the complexity of his problem. This is just a simple/quick solution...

Answer (score 4):

Just to add, there's also the [`var_export`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php) function. I've found this useful for certain situations. From the manual:

> var_export — Outputs or returns a
> parsable string representation of a
> variable

Example:

```
<?php
$a = array (1, 2, array ("a", "b", "c"));
var_export($a);
?>
```

Returns this output (which can then be converted back to an array using [eval()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php)):

```
array (
  0 => 1,
  1 => 2,
  2 => 
  array (
    0 => 'a',
    1 => 'b',
    2 => 'c',
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function makestring($array)
  {
  $outval = '';
  foreach($array as $key=>$value)
    {
    if(is_array($value))
      {
      $outval .= makestring($value);
      }
    else
      {
      $outval .= $value;
      }
    }
  return $outval;
  }
```