# Converting array to string and then back in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I created a array using PHP

```
$userarray = array('UserName'=>$username,'UserId'=>$userId,'UserPicURL'=>$userPicURL);
```

How can I convert this array into a string in PHP and back from string into an array. This is kind of a requirement. Could someone please advice on how this can be acheived.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert PHP array string into an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/684553/convert-php-array-string-into-an-array)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can convert any PHP data-type but resources into a string by serializing it:

```
$string = serialize($array);
```

And back into it's original form by unserializing it again:

```
$array = unserialize($string);
```

A [serialized](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) array is in string form. It can be converted into an array again by unserializing it.

The same does work with [`json_encode` / -`_decode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) for your array as well:

```
$string = json_encode($array);
$array = json_decode($string);
```

Comment: Note the difference between using serialize/unserialize vs imlpode/explode is that the former will work regardless of the contents of the values - with the example provided by Alex, the method will fail if one of the valuse contains a space

Answer (score 1):

use the function implode(separator,array) which return a string from the elements of an array.

and then the function explode ( string $delimiter , string $string [, int $limit ] ) to revert it back to an array

```
$array_as_string = implode(" ",$userarray);
$new_array = explode(" ",$array_as_string);
```

Comment: Thanks ! Worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either

```
$userarray = array('UserName' => $username, 'UserId' => $userId, 'UserPicURL' => $userPicURL);
$string = json_encode($userarray);
$backtoarray = json_decode($string);
```

or

```
$userarray = array('UserName' => $username, 'UserId' => $userId, 'UserPicURL' => $userPicURL);
$string = serialize($userarray);
$backtoarray = unserialize($string);
```

The first one uses XML storage, and the second uses JSON.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me to get array again:

```php
$backtoarray = (array) json_decode($string);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).