# How do I convert a string of an array to an array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

This seems like a simple task, but I haven't been able to find a way to do this. I have an output of data stored as a string like this:

```
$rawData = "array('first' => '$first', 'middle' => '$middle', 'last' => '$last')";
```

What I simply need to do is convert it to this array:

```
$arrData = array('first' => "$first", 'middle' => "$middle", 'last' => "$last");
```

The closest I have been able to get is this shown below with print_r results:

```
$Data = explode(',', $rawData);

Array
(
    [0] => 'first' => '$first'
    [1] =>  'middle' => '$middle'
    [2] =>  'last' => '$last'
)
```

What I need is this:

```
Array
(
    [first] => $first
    [middle] => $middle
    [last] => $last
)
```

Must be something very easy I have overlooked.  Please help.

Comment: I have spent a lot of time looking at similar questions on this site and looking at w3schools and other references.  I know I must be overlooking something simple, but can't find it.  Something more than just a -1 vote would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: I saw that this fellow had a similar question, but he was starting with the array.  I have to start with the string. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/684553/convert-php-array-string-into-an-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does what you want ( i think ), even if its not pretty

```
<?php

$arr = array();
$first = 'one';
$middle = 'two';
$last = 'three';

$rawData = "array('first' => '$first', 'middle' => '$middle', 'last' => '$last')";

$arrData = explode( ',', ( str_replace( array( 'array(\'', '=>', '\')', '\'' ), array( '', '%@@%', '', '' ), $rawData ) ) );

foreach( $arrData as $val ) {
  $v = explode( '%@@%', $val );
  $arr[trim($v[0])] = trim($v[1]);
}

echo '<pre>' . print_r( $arr, true ) . '</pre>';

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for replying Tom.  I get the following error:

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in: for the $arrData[] = explode( '%@@%', $val )[1];

Comment: OK, got the edit and it is working now.  Thanks so much for replying.  I thought there would be a much simpler way to do this!

Comment: Thanks Tom,  this is working in my program now. I'm so glad to be unstuck!

Answer (score 2):

Depending on where you get the string from, you may use `eval`. It's highly recommended to not use this function, whenever the contents of that string may be influenced directly or indirectly by a user, see hint at http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php. And it must contain valid PHP syntax, thus putting it into a try/catch block is necessary:

```
$evalArray = false;
$first = 'a';
$middle = 'b';
$last = 'c';

$rawData = "array('first' => '$first', 'middle' => '$middle', 'last' => '$last')";

try {
    $evalArray = eval($rawData);
} catch ( $e )
{
    echo "parsing failed " . $e
}

print_r($evalArray );
```

Comment: this quote at the end was quite revealing!
 "If eval() is the answer, you're almost certainly asking the
wrong question." -- Rasmus Lerdorf, BDFL of PHP
Thanks again.

Comment: Right. Bt in order to re-design that, much more information is needed as disclosed in your question!

Comment: I understand. I was appreciating your caution. The whole data string comes from an on-line form.  It was cleansed and encrypted before insertion into a sql db. I am pulling it out of the db, de-crypting and then trying to use the information for it's intended purpose. Anyway, the whole string fell into your warning: "whenever the contents of that string may be influenced directly or indirectly by a user". I'm glad you brought that to my attention.  Thanks!