# Coversion string to array

Tags: arrays, string, laravel, object

This is my String data

```
[  
   'EDUCATION_LEVEL'   =>'MIDDLE_LEVEL',
   'EDUCATION_PROFESSIONAL'   =>'APPRENTICESHIP',
   'Family_Father'   =>'M.Sharif #03312887233',
   'PROFILE_IMAGE_1'   =>'"file_type" => "image",
   "file_saved_path"   => "public/images/34_php4A2A.tmp.jpg"',
   'COWORKER_REFERENCE_1'   =>'Mr. xyz work place partner #03312887233',
   'COWORKER_REFERENCE_3'   =>'Mr. Abc work place partner #03312887233',
   'BIRTH_CITY'   =>'Rahim Yar Khan',
   'BIRTHPLACE_PROVINCE'   =>'Punjab',
   'BIRTH_DISTRICT'   =>'SadiqAbad',
   'WORKING_PROVINCE'   =>'Sindh',
   'WORKING_PROVINCE_CITY'   =>'Karachi East',
   'WORKING_CITY_AREA'   =>'Gulsan-i-Iqbal',

]◀"
```

I tried many options which found on net

```
$data = (array)($chardata);
$data = (object)($chardata);
```

I want object or array from which i can get vakues like

```
$data['EDUCATION_LEVEL'];
or
$data->EDUCATION_LEVEL
```

Comment: Can you do `json_encode(your_array)`?

Comment: i think you are looking for this https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php  $data = unserialize($chardata);

Comment: might also be a possible duplicate to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684553/convert-php-array-string-into-an-array