# Convert multidimensional array string to array

Tags: php

There is a built-in function in PHP or something clean for convert multidimensional array string to array?

String like:

```
['text', 'te\'"x2t', "text", "te\"x'#t", true, True, [false, False, 100, +100], -100, + 10, -   20]
```

each value can be strings(+ escaped characters), boolean, int(+sign) and array which make it a multidimensional array.

To:

```
Array
(
    [0] => text
    [1] => te'"x2t
    [2] => text
    [3] => te"x'#t
    [4] => 1
    [5] => 1
    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => 
            [2] => 100
            [3] => 100
        )

    [7] => -100
    [8] => 10
    [9] => -20
)
```

I wrote a regex for this, which make match valid to the string under those statements.
So it will not match if the string not follows after the rules.

```
(?<_ARRAY>\[\s*(?:(?:(?P>VALUE)|(?P>_ARRAY))\s*,\s*)*(?:(?:(?P>VALUE)|(?P>_ARRAY))\s*)\])
```

Now I want to save the values as they are, without any changes.

It can be done with eval, but far as I know, eval is risky and I wonder if there is a better solution for this.

```
if (preg_match('/(?<_ARRAY>\[\s*(?:(?:(?P>VALUE)|(?P>_ARRAY))\s*,\s*)*(?:(?:(?P>VALUE)|(?P>_ARRAY))\s*)\])/', $array))
    eval("\$array = $array;");
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert PHP array string into an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684553/convert-php-array-string-into-an-array)

Comment: @thmsdnnr I don't see anything in the duplicate that really helps OP as the answers all depend on having a valid array to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

With a bit of inspiration from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6462578/regex-to-match-all-instances-not-inside-quotes/23667311#23667311), I've come up with this, which seems to work. Basically the string is split on commas and left and right square brackets that do not occur within quotes, or on single/double quoted strings and each part is processed to turn it into a valid JSON value. The string is then put back together and converted into an array using [`json_decode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php):

```
$str = "['text', 'te\\'\"x,2t', \"tex,t\", \"te\\\"x'#t\", true, True, [false, False, 100, +100], -100, + 10, -   20]";
$parts = preg_split('/\s*("(?:\\\\"|[^"])*"|\'(?:\\\\\'|[^\'])*\')\s*|\s*([,\[\]])\s*/', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
foreach ($parts as &$part) {
    if (preg_match("/^'(.*)'/", $part, $matches)) {
        $part = '"' . str_replace(array('"', "\\'"), array('\\"', "'"), $matches[1]) . '"';
        continue;
    }
    $lpart = strtolower($part);
    if ($lpart == 'true' || $lpart == 'false') {
        $part = $lpart;
        continue;
    }
    if (preg_match('/^\+\s*(\d+)$/', $part, $matches)) {
        $part = $matches[1];
        continue;
    }
    if (preg_match('/^-\s*(\d+)$/', $part, $matches)) {
        $part = '-' . $matches[1];
        continue;
    }
}
$json = implode('', $parts);
var_dump(json_decode($json));
```

Output:

```
array(10) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "text"
  [1]=>
  string(8) "te'"x,2t"
  [2]=>
  string(5) "tex,t"
  [3]=>
  string(7) "te"x'#t"
  [4]=>
  bool(true)
  [5]=>
  bool(true)
  [6]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    bool(false)
    [1]=>
    bool(false)
    [2]=>
    int(100)
    [3]=>
    int(100)
  }
  [7]=>
  int(-100)
  [8]=>
  int(10)
  [9]=>
  int(-20)
}
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/jrBhD)

**Original Answer**

If you convert all the single quotes to double quotes, the string is valid JSON and can be decoded using [`json_decode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php):

```
$str = "['text', 'text', 100, ['text', false], false, ['text', 200], 'text']";
$json = str_replace("'", '"', $str);
print_r(json_decode($json));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => text
    [1] => text
    [2] => 100
    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => text
            [1] => 
        )    
    [4] => 
    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => text
            [1] => 200
        )    
    [6] => text
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/GoVR4)

Comment: Ohh, so this is the reason why json_decode didn't work when I tried.
However,  I can't use it because some of the strings can be with escaped quotes and others with double-quotes.
With extra code, it can be done, but I wonder if there is something simpler for this.

Comment: @Namixo Can you post the actual string you're working with, or at least a representative example that shows all of the potential edge cases you're dealing with? Otherwise, you can expect simplistic answers that won't likely relate to your use case. Thanks.

Comment: @Namixo it still ought to be possible to convert your string into valid JSON, although obviously a bit more complex. Other than `eval` or a really complicated splitting on commas (but not within quotes or `[]`) I'm not sure what other options you have. Can you add some other sample data to your question?

Comment: @Nick I edited the post, do you think eval is a good solution for this? far as I know, eval is evil :-) thanks for helping!

Comment: @Namixo is it possible to have commas inside the string values?

Comment: @Nick Yes, the string can be any character.

Comment: @Namixo I've updated my answer with something that I think should work for pretty much any input...

Comment: @Nick thanks! it works except you have a multi backslash in a row that ignores them. I will dive to it later and give you an update.